# Meteor exception when specific item is added to collection

Tags: meteor

I have implemented infinite scroll for a 1.2k item collection. It works great apart from when scrolling past certain elements - an exception is raised when they are rendered and I can't figure out why...

```
Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
    at Patcher.match (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1539:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1352:23
    at visitNodes (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1319:11)
    at visitNodes (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1320:9)
    at visitNodes (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1320:9)
    at visitNodes (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1320:9)
    at patch (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:1333:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:698:7
    at LiveRange.operate (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:490:9)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:693:11 debug.js:41
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Associated codelines?  Are you using Deps client or server side?

Comment: Can you render the specific element individually, and it only fails in a context of other elements, or does it fail no matter what?

Comment: Can you link what kind of infinite scroll implementation you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had ran into this issue:

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/TypeError_-_Cannot_read_property_nodeName_of_null

I had some {{constant}} sections in my template and when I removed them the error stopped.